# How to read a higher voltage digital input?

Tags: arduino-mega, voltage-level, digital

Lets suppose I have a circuit with a car battery, a switch and a led. The led will turn on when the switch is closed, and turn off if it's not. I want to remove the led from the circuit and put an Arduino in that place to "read" when the circuit is closed or open.

I'm a good programmer, so the code is not the real problem. I only want to know how to do this without damaging the board.

How can I do this?

Comment: Lookup voltage dividers.

Comment: @Gerben What should be the destination voltage to enter into a digital input pin on the arduino? 5v?

Comment: 5v indeed. But I'd leave a bit of margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gerben says, voltage dividers are a good place to start. To elaborate on the topic, you can use a combination of voltage dividers, zener diodes and clamping diodes.

This [EE.SE post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35807/how-would-i-design-a-protection-clipper-circuit-for-adc-input) has some good info about this, related to ADC, but still the same.

First off, a voltage divider circuit is easily found on the internet,

1. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=voltage+divider&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)
2. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider)

This circuit from [Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/voldiv.html) shows the basics:
[image: Hyperphysics]

---

To add more protection to this so as not to go over the max I/O voltage of the MCU, you can add a zener diode on the **V<sub>out</sub>**. 
That would give you something like this([Olins](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/48317/46355)):

[image: credit to Olin]

This will give you the desired range to give legitimate High and Low on an I/O.

---

If you wanted to forgo the voltage divider and zener you can use [clamping diodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamper_%28electronics%29) to the microcontroller supply voltage Vcc. This will give a range that will not damage the I/O.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHrneK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 10k resistor is there to limit the current through the diodes, which are Schottky diodes.

---

Another method, which I have used before and is reliable, is to use a diode and two resistors like below:

[image]

The logic is that, when the input `IN` is > Vcc(5V) the signal on the I/O `_IN` will be the voltage of the pull_up resistor `R2`, if it is low or floating the signal will be low. R1 also gives a known logic state if the input floats.

*Edit*: Changed the image to proper logic flow.

Comment: Be careful that the IN and _IN pins in the last circuit are "logically" swapped, i.e. the signal goes RIGHT to LEFT: IN is the input, _IN is the microcontroller

Comment: @frarugi87 - I copied it straight from a schematic I'm working on(makes sense to me, as I did it ;)), thanks for pointing it out, I will edit it tomorrow when I get a chance.

Comment: Of course, but it took me a while to understand it ;) anyway thank you for sharing, I'll tkeep it in my mind next time I'll need this kind of converters ;)